# Handling list of lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am newbie at `Prolog` and Logic-programming in general. I'm trying to practice from a textbook I have and there was the following question: Consider a list of lists that looks for example like:

```
[[spanish, white], [italian, white], [italian, red], [canadian, blue]]
```

We will define 'harmony' to be a set of unique elements which are located in only one sub-list. Each index of the inner-list represents something like: nationality or color. From the example above, `[canadian, blue]` is "harmony" but `[italian, white]` is not because `italian` also in `[italian, red]`.

I'm trying to create a relation which iterates through the sub-lists and tries to create the best "harmony". For the example above, we should check the first sub-list; `[spanish, white]` and for each element check if there exists another sub-list that contains that element. If they are unique then it is "harmony", otherwise we should check if we can somehow reduce one of those lists. The output should be:

```
[[spanish, white], [italian, red], [canadian, blue]]
```

Explanation: `spanish` is connected to `white` so we should not touch it, but `italian` contained both with `white` and `red`. Then we can understand that `italian` must be connected to `red` because `white is with`spanish`.

The final goal is to have a list of unique sub-lists. You can think of it as a system of equations and we want to solve it.

Another example:

```
[[spanish, white, 5], [italian, red,4], [canadian, blue,2],[canadian,red,2],[spanish, blue,4]]
```

Output:

```
 [[spanish, white, 5], [italian, red,4], [canadian, blue,2]]
```

Explanation: let's look at `[spanish, white, 5]`. We know that `spanish` also located in `[spanish, blue,4]`, but `blue` is located also in `[canadian, blue,2]`. `canadian` is not located anywhere else so `blue` belongs to `canadian`. That means `spanish` gets `white` (and then also `5`). `canadian` gets `2` and that means `italian` gets `4` and `blue`.

I was trying to use `findall` but without any success. I feel like there is to much information and it confuses me.

What would be a good solution to that problem from the textbook?

**EDIT**:

There would be always only one possible solution. if you get something like `[[spanish, white], [italian, white]]` then you don't have any additional information and you should leave it as it is.

I was trying to solve it again but without any success. I tried to somehow create a hashmap which will contain all the information but it feels to me that it is not a `Prolog` solution. I think that `findall` might solve it but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: What is it supposed to do with `[[spanish,white],[spanish,red]]`? What is it supposed to do with `[[spanish,white],[spanish,white]]`? What is it supposed to do with `[[spanish,white],[canadian,white]]`?

Comment: If you consider `[[italian,red,1], [italian,blue,2]]`, is the combination `[italian,red,2]` in harmony?

Comment: There is promised to be solution so you won't get across with that kind of input. You can think of that as a system of equations so there is always one possible solution.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Since the position of values in sub lists is fixed, and all sub lists are complete:

```
harmony(As,Bs) :- maplist(dif,As,Bs).

harmonies(L,R) :-
    forall((select(A,L,S),member(B,S)), harmony(A,B))
    ->  R=L
    ;   select(_,L,T), harmonies(T,R)
    .

creasing_harmonies(L,R) :-
    setof(D-T,(harmonies(L,T),length(T,D)),R).
```

Not sure what the 'best harmony' could be. Assuming it's the longer one:

```
?- creasing_harmonies([[spanish, white, 5], [italian, red,4], [canadian, blue,2],[canadian,red,2],[spanish, blue,4]],L),last(L,B).
L = [1-[[canadian, blue, 2]], 1-[[canadian, red, 2]], 1-[[italian, red, 4]], 1-[[spanish, blue, 4]], 1-[[spanish, white|...]], 2-[[canadian|...], [...|...]], 2-[[...|...]|...], 2-[...|...], ... - ...|...],
B = 3-[[spanish, white, 5], [italian, red, 4], [canadian, blue, 2]].
```

If your Prolog doesn't have dif/2 or maplist/3, an approximation could be

```
harmony([],[]).
harmony([E|As],[E|Bs]) :- !, fail.
harmony([_|As],[_|Bs]) :- harmony(As,Bs).
```

*edit*

So far, it's very inefficient. To get a solution, must reduce the search space:

```
harmonies(L,R) :-
    length(L,N),N>4,
    (   forall((select(A,L,S),member(B,S)), harmony(A,B))
    ->  R=L
    ;   select(_,L,T), harmonies(T,R)
    ).
```

But let see how many 'solution' we have right now

```
?- test_data(L),aggregate(count,harmonies(L,R),C).
L = [[table, green, alex, coffee, prince], [keyboard, green, alex, coffee, bookA], [keyboard, yellow, alex, water, bookA], [cup, red, alex, water, bookB], [computer, white, john, beer|...], [cup, red, birds|...], [keyboard, green|...], [keyboard|...], [...|...]|...],
R = [[table, green, alex, coffee, prince], [computer, white, john, beer, bookD], [cup, red, birds, milk, bookC], [keyboard, yellow, sabrina, water, bookA], [dane, blue, sasha, tea|...]],
C = 5040.
```

5040 duplicates ! Better to stop at the first solution on a fixed length.

```
harmonies(L,N,R) :-
    length(L,M),M>=N,
    (   forall((select(A,L,S),member(B,S)), harmony(A,B))
    ->  R=L
    ;   select(_,L,T), harmonies(T,R)
    ).

?- test_data(L),harmonies(L,5,R).
L = [[table, green, alex, coffee, prince], [keyboard, green, alex, coffee, bookA], [keyboard, yellow, alex, water, bookA], [cup, red, alex, water, bookB], [computer, white, john, beer|...], [cup, red, birds|...], [keyboard, green|...], [keyboard|...], [...|...]|...],
R = [[table, green, alex, coffee, prince], [computer, white, john, beer, bookD], [cup, red, birds, milk, bookC], [keyboard, yellow, sabrina, water, bookA], [dane, blue, sasha, tea|...]] .
```

Comment: Wow! That really goes to show the elegance of Prolog!

Comment: @CapelliC thanks for the awesome short answer! I tried to run it on an example and it end up with `ERROR: Out of global stack`.  @firefrorefiddle's answer return the answer immediately. What could be the issue? Also, Can you show me how to replace `dif` and `maplist` please?

Comment: Could you post your test data that crashed ? I'd like to fix my code... About dif/2 and maplist/3 alternatives, see the harmony/2 definition at bottom.

Comment: I don't get your edit. `harmonies` gets `2` or `3` arguments?

Comment: they are different predicates, but right now harmonies/2 has hard coded a limit of at least 5....

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
% Here is an interpretation of your defintion: For each List head (e.g. spanish,
% italian) select exactly one element from the input list. Then, check that the 
% selection is all in harmony. Please clarify if this is not the correct interpretation!

solution(List, Elements) :-
    select_all_heads(List, Elements),
    all_harmony(Elements).


% All elements (Elements) are in harmony when each of them (Element) is in 
% harmony with the rest (Others).

all_harmony([]).
all_harmony(Elements) :-
    foreach((member(Element, Elements),
             select(Element, Elements, Others)),
            harmony(Element, Others)).


% One sublist (Element) is in harmony with a list of other sublists (Others), if 
% it is either empty, or its Head is not contained in the heads of the other sublists
% (OthersHeads) and its tail (Tail) is also in harmony with the tails of the other
% lists (OthersTails).

harmony([], _).
harmony(Element, Others) :-
    Element=[Head|Tail],
    maplist(head_tail, Others, OthersHeads, OthersTails),
    \+ member(Head, OthersHeads),
    harmony(Tail, OthersTails).


% A list consists of a head (H) and a tail (T). This helper predicate can be used with maplist.

head_tail([H|T], H, T).


% Find all the heads, then select a member-sublist for each head.

select_all_heads(List, Elements) :-
    heads(List, Heads),
    select_all_heads(Heads, List, Elements).


% For each head element, select one sublist. Select the other heads from the rest.

select_all_heads([], _, []).
select_all_heads([Head|Heads], List, [Element|Elements]) :-
    select_head(Head, Element, List, List1),
    select_all_heads(Heads, List1, Elements).


% We need to know all the heads, so we know how many elements to select. 
% setof gives us a list without duplicates.

heads(List, Heads) :-
    setof(Head,
          T^member([Head|T], List),
          Heads).


% select one member (Element) of the input list (List) with a specific head (Head)
%  and leave the rest (Rest).

select_head(Head, Element, List, Rest) :-
    Element = [Head|_],
    select(Element, List, Rest).
```

Test:

```
 ?- test1(L), solution(L, S).
  L = [[spanish, white], [italian, white], [italian, red], [canadian, blue]],
  S = [[canadian, blue], [italian, red], [spanish, white]] ;
false.

?- test2(L), solution(L, S).
  L = [[spanish, white, 5], [italian, red, 4], [canadian, blue, 2], [canadian, red, 2], [spanish, blue, 4]],
  S = [[canadian, blue, 2], [italian, red, 4], [spanish, white, 5]] ;
false.
```

This is not optimal, performance-wise, because there is no intermediate reduction in the set of answers, but it should be alright to illustrate Prolog.

Comment: Nice solution !